Error on creating One2many widget in Odoo 16
The idea is simple, I want to show all the data in one2many in an ordered list:
So simple. Should be so easy, but I have wasted 10 hours on it, still without a sign of success :(
Here is my js:
odoo.define('obki.accordion_widget', function (require) {
    'use strict';

    var core = require('web.core');
    var AbstractField = require('web.AbstractField');
    var field_registry = require('web.field_registry');
    var QWeb = core.qweb;

    var AccordionWidget = AbstractField.extend({
        // The template for the widget
        template: 'AccordionWidget',
        supportedFieldTypes: ['one2many'],
        // Render the widget
        _render: function () {
            var info = this.value;
            console.log('######### info: ', info);
            debugger; //it's not even executed
            this.$el.text('Accordion Widget Content'); // Display the Accordion name
        },
    });

    // Register the widget
    field_registry.add('accordion_widget', AccordionWidget);

    // return AccordionWidget;

    return {
        AccordionWidget: AccordionWidget,
    };
});

Here my XML:
<t t-name="AccordionWidget" owl="1">
    <ol>
    <t t-foreach="record.tac_ids" t-as="line">
        <li>
            <div><t t-esc="line.name"/></div>
        </li>
    </t>
    </ol>        
</t>

The result is always:

Missing widget: accordion_widget for field of type text

I have tried to copy another code from another 3rd_party plugin like this:
/** @odoo-module **/
import { registry } from '@web/core/registry';
import { X2ManyField } from '@web/views/fields/x2many/x2many_field';

export class Accordion extends X2ManyField {
}

Accordion.template = 'AccordionWidget';
registry.category('fields').add('accordion_widget', Accordion);

It seems working, the widget is registered and shown on the form. But unfortunately, I don't know how to access the data. How to read the field_ids data? I have tried this.field_ids, props.field_ids, props.record, props.everything, nothing works.

The one2many lines should be accessible using:
this.props.value.records

The error is raised from the new field registry, try the following code (first example upgraded):
Component:
/** @odoo-module **/

import { registry } from "@web/core/registry";
import { Component } from "@odoo/owl";

const fieldRegistry = registry.category("fields");


export class AccordionWidget extends Component {

}

AccordionWidget.template = "AccordionWidget"
AccordionWidget.supportedTypes = ["one2many"];

// Register the widget
fieldRegistry.add('accordion_widget', AccordionWidget);

Template:
<t t-foreach="this.props.value.records" t-as="line" t-key="line_index">
   <li>
       <div><t t-esc="line.data.name"/></div>
   </li>
</t>

t-key attribute is required

thank you so moch @kenly, unfortunatelly I can not test it yet. I activate my old odoo 11 project, and suddenly when I come back to odoo 16, the odoo 16 all messed up. looks like all the .scss are not working. I am using mac, i have use nvm to manage different npm. different less version. but still doesnt work. I will test it very soon after my odoo 16 come back online again. Thank you

oh wow, it works. thank you very much.
is there possible if i want to take another field? let say, i have a field notes
but i can not access it with line.data.notes, its empty

How did you add the notes field? You can access the record data using this.props.record and the one2many field using this.record.data.tac_ids.records

actually i am losing on this work lol. i changed my mind. all i want to do is just make a custom tree view for one2many. finally i did it by inhering the one2many widget. thank you @kenly sir. you're so helpful.
